# Bootable uefi/gpt usb

Tags: boot

I need to create a bootable usb with Windows 7 on Ubuntu but it seems like I am doing something wrong. I have tried it 4 times but couldn't get it to work. First I formated the usb with fat32     in gparted then created a gpt table on it and copied iso contents to it with this command: 7z x isoFileName.iso
 -o/media/[usb_mount_point]. Everything went fine but when I tried to boot from it nothing happened. I get a black screen then the control is transfered to the following boot entry i.e. grub. Could someone give me a step-by-step guide for absolute super noob on how to do it. Thanks.
p.s. I have done this before on Windows with Rufus with the same bios settings but now I don't have access to a Windows machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)

Comment: I understand that this question may be asked before but as I said I need a step-by-step guide on how to create a uefi/gpt bootable usb

Comment: Another mini question: Do I need to format the usb with ntfs FS in order to make it uefi/gpt compatible

Comment: I want to install Windows 7 on my pc anew after formatting the hard drive.

Comment: From this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu/489556#489556 *A USB flash drive that is 4GB or larger has enough capacity to make installation media for versions of Windows up to Windows 10. Native UEFI booting is supported for Windows 7 and later images (limited to the FAT filesystem as the target device).*

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it and let you know if it worked.

Comment: I remember that for windows 10 it was sufficient to copy the contents of the iso file to a USB drive. I don't remember if it was formatted as fat32 or NTFS, though. Did you add the .efi file to the trusted files in your uefi setup?

Comment: When creating a bootable usb on Windows with rufus I always formatted with fat 32 both for 7 and 10 and it worked pretty well. For the .efi file I don't understand your question. If it is needed please tell me how to do it.

Comment: I asked my friend to create the usb for me on his Windows pc and then tried to boot from it but I couldn't. I guess I am making this another problem but still the problem persists: I can't boot from usb. This is the 3rd usb that i have tried. Could you suggest something around this?

Comment: Thank you karel for your support. I managed to create a usb with that method but it seems like the problem is elsewhere as the pc won't boot from any usb.